# ntfsprogs versus ntfs-3g

Tags: linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Can someone explain the difference between ntfsprogs and ntfs-3g? And which one is better?

Is ntfsprogs uses ntfs-3g or they have no relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NTFS-3G is an open source cross-platform implementation of the Microsoft Windows NTFS file system with read-write support.

Ntfsprogs is a collection of free Unix utilities for managing the NTFS filesystem used by Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000, Windows NT 4.0, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 on a harddisk partition.

-Wikipedia